# How can I use varible from another function?

Tags: java

For printing the value of factorial, I want to use the value of fact in the facto() function. How can I achieve this?

I have tried declaring variables i and fact in the facto() function.

```
public class Factorial {
    int fact=1;
    int n=5,i=1;

    void facto()
    {

        for(i=n;i>=1;i--)
        {
            fact=fact*i;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Factorial obj1= new Factorial();
        System.out.println(obj1.fact);
    }
}
```

The answer I'm getting is what it gets the value from the class and is initialized with 1. I want to get 120 as the solution.

Comment: *"I want to get 120 as the solution"* That's only going to happen if you **call the `facto` method**.

Comment: That would seem to be the key point here, no?  It's not primarily about getting access to the result, it's about the need to run the code that will produce the result.

Comment: And don't call them functions. Call them methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Void function means the function that does not return any value, so it is wrong to use void function.

If you want to get a value from the method. You should use **a method that can return a value** as following :

```
public class Factorial {


    public int facto()
    {
    int fact=1;
    int n=5,i=1;

        for(i=n;i>=1;i--)
        {
            fact=fact*i;
        }
     return fact;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Factorial obj1= new Factorial();
        System.out.println(obj1.facto());
    }
}
```

ps : I have changed the place of variables to scope of facto() method with warning of @Idle_Mind. 
Because  this has a slight side effect in that if you call facto() more than once you'll get different results. To "fix" this you could re-initialize "fact" to 1 inside facto()

Comment: Note that this has a slight side effect in that if you call `facto()` more than once you'll get different results.  To "fix" this you could re-initialize "fact" to 1 inside `facto()`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use fields. Use a parameter and a return value.

```
public class Factorial {
    private int facto(int n) {
        int fact = 1;
        for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
            fact = fact * i;
        }
        return fact;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Factorial obj1 = new Factorial();
        System.out.println(obj1.facto(5));
    }
}
```